# Regex seems correct, but doesn't match with XSLT

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, saxon

I have this string:

> "und", 3.96036662358691, 3.3195020746888, 3.2907085875176, 3.02795262671161, 3.5162776568275, 3.6582196231319, 4.25539102528011, 2.66244838424718, 2.92641494865261, 2.76262283971535,

I want to get the first decimal and the comma afterwards (3.96036662358691,).

Therefore I'm using this regex:

```
(^"\w+",\s)(\d+\.\d+,)
```

To use the regex in XSLT, I escaped the quotes, so the regex is now:

```
(^&quot;\w+&quot;,\s)(\d+\.\d+,)
```

A snippet from the XSLT:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(^&quot;\w+&quot;,\s)(\d+\.\d+,)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
```

I'm using Oxygen, XSLT 3.0 and Saxon-PE 11.4.

Why is my regex only matching when looking for the pattern in the file, but not when using it with XSLT?

---

Some more information:

This is a snippet from the XML file (with word frequencies):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml>"name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8", "name9", "name10",
"und", 3.96036662358691, 3.3195020746888, 3.2907085875176, 3.02795262671161, 3.5162776568275, 3.6582196231319, 4.25539102528011, 2.66244838424718, 2.92641494865261, 2.76262283971535,
"sie", 1.74547291174592, 2.69105265278169, 1.79199906147349, 4.57921899704663, 2.02015087843653, 0.786224821312541, 2.4266651652497, 5.35571214331204, 1.5944714693846, 2.0382921043714,
"die", 1.87916870924135, 2.7111952624582, 2.32578601595495, 2.36866441931923, 2.16444736975343, 2.00129954515919, 2.77011429536625, 2.09749984592313, 2.3009806192572, 2.05947136563877,</xml>
```

This is a snippet from my XSLT so far:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version="3.0"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
            expand-text="yes">
            
            <xsl:template match="*:xml/text()">
                
                <!-- copy all words to the very top  -->
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(&quot;(\w+)&quot;,)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
                        
                <!-- copy all word frequencies for name1 -->
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(^&quot;\w+&quot;,\s)(\d+\.\d+,)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:text>"name1",</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>

<!-- after that: copy all frequencies for name2 etc.  -->

    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

All in all, I'm trying to reformat a txt file to get the correct format for csv.

Comment: Inside a regular expression pattern, the character `^` denotes the start of a string so given that your string in the real XML input starts with `"name1", "name2",..` that regular expression using `^` to find a single quoted word followed by a comma and a number is not going to match. I guess you want to drop the `^`.

Comment: Of course, thanks! I wrapped every new line in a <l>-tag, now it works!

Comment: The structure of the input is difficult to understand. What is the expected output here? There may be a simpler way to approach this (e.g. by using `tokenize()`).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quite explained what you are after but I would think that adding the `flags="m"` attribute in

```
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(^&quot;\w+&quot;,\s)(\d+\.\d+,)" flags="m">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:text>"name1",</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
```

is what helps with your complete, multi-line input as that way `^` matches the beginning of each line and not simply of the input string.